# TF225001: Creating a build definition requires a build controller be defined for this team project collection

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, tfsbuild

I have installed TFS 2013 Express edition. I also want to activate the Continuous integration option, but when I click New Build Definition, I see the error below:

TF225001: Creating a build definition requires a build controller be defined for this team project collection.There may not be any controllers configured or you may not have the permissions to view them. Contract your Team Foundation Server administrator.

My Visual Studio is 2013 Community Edition and my Team Foundation Server is 2013 express edition.

Answer (score 2):

You need to install and configure a TFS Build Controller.  Normally you would do this from the TFS Install, not sure if TFS Community includes the ability to be used as a build server also though.

Comment: TFS Express is full featured, just for smaller teams. I almost universally recommend looking at VSO instead of TFS express, since they both fill the same niche for small teams, but is easy to scale when the team grows.